# Play! Framework with Less/CSS

Tags: css, playframework, less

I am using the [Play!](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Home) Framework ( 2.6.2 ), Scala ( 2.12.2 ) and trying to integrate [LESS](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-less#sbt-less) into it.

I was using [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AssetsLess) tutorial on their documentation website.

In my build.sbt file this is the code in place:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, SbtWeb)

includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less" 
excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less"

LessKeys.compress in Assets := true
```

And in my plugin.sbt file I've added:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.2")
```

I've got 2 files with .less extention. main.less and login.less in a /css folder under /public directory.

When I compile and run the project in my target folder the files stay as .less files and don't get compiled into .css files.

In my HTML template code I have this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("css/login.css")">
```

The link to the stylesheet works if I change the extention from login.less to login.css but the variables don't seem to be accessible in the login.less file.

The link to the stylesheet doesn't work with the .css extention as expected because the framework doesn't seem to be compiling the files to .css, it just seems to leave them as .less files. Therefore I'm just getting a 404 on the .css file. If i change the extention in the link to .less it then works fine but variables I've imported from main.less to login.less don't work.

Is there a step I'm missing? Can somebody explain why the framework would not compile the .less files to .css files in my target folder?

**EDIT 1:** After trying the fix suggested by @marcospereira: I think the application is trying to compile both files but also returns me an error and application doesn't run at all.

```
[info] LESS compiling on 2 source(s)
    -------
    Unexpected exception
    JsTaskFailure: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/mozilla/javascript/Context;Lorg/mozilla/javascript/Scriptable;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at io.apigee.trireme.node10.main.trireme._c_anonymous_1(trireme.js:37)
        at io.apigee.trireme.node10.main.trireme.call(trireme.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3102)
        at io.apigee.trireme.node10.main.trireme.call(trireme.js)
        at io.apigee.trireme.core.internal.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:762)
        at io.apigee.trireme.core.internal.ScriptRunner$4.run(ScriptRunner.java:702)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:488)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:504)
        at io.apigee.trireme.core.internal.ScriptRunner.call(ScriptRunner.java:697)
        at io.apigee.trireme.core.ScriptFuture.run(ScriptFuture.java:183)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    -------
```

Comment: I have a similar PlayFramework version (2.3.8) and for me the .css file is generated MINIFIED only. Could you check the `target/web/less/ ...etc` folder of your compiled output for the actual .css file names? For me the generated .css is called `main.min.css`.

Comment: I do not have /web/less directory.

Comment: You could try searching for *.css files in your output directory. (In my case this output directory is as described above, of course yours will differ, depending on your project settings ..)

Comment: I did, nothing came up in the whole /target folder

Comment: There is not a single .css in your /target folder?

Comment: I've got css files in my /target but none that start with login or main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install node.js on your machine.

If you do not have node.js installed then it will fall back to the Trireme Java-based JavaScript engine, which does not work very well and is resulting in that error

Answer (score 1):

Managed assets needs to be inside `app/assets`. From [the docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AssetsLess):

> Compilable assets in Play **must be defined in the `app/assets` directory**. They are handled by the build process, and LESS sources are compiled into standard CSS files. The generated CSS files are distributed as standard resources into the same public/ folder as the unmanaged assets, meaning that there is no difference in the way you use them once compiled.

So, you need to move your files from `public/css` to `app/assets/css`.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix the problem. I see that it should technically but appears to have thrown an error. I've updated the question with the error if you could have a look. It seems to be trying to compile the the 2 source files login.less and main.less but failing after that.

Comment: Is it possible to share a small project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'll give it a shot

Comment: I think I've done it. If you take this project and do an: sbt run it should recriate my problem. https://github.com/DragomirAdapptive/testing_less_at2